# Update Query Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to update a field inside one table, "Todays_Deliveries", from another table called "Current_Delivery". The field is a number field called "Remaining" which describes how many units there are of a particular item left on the daily deliveries.

The "Todays_Deliveries" table is generated using an APPEND query from another master table with every delivery stored in it. Everytime the user opens a delivery on a form anything in the "Current_Delivery" table is removed using a DELETE query and then generated based on the delivery selected using an APPEND query from the "Todays_Deliveries" table.

Both tables have identical fields and identical values, given one is generated from the data of the other.

I have tried to create an UPDATE query to update the "Todays_Deliveries" table when a user edits the "Current_Delivery" table but it doesn't work. I recieve no error messages the field just doesn't update. The steps I took were as follows:

1. Add both tables.
2. Change to UPDATE query.
3. Link tables using the Remaining field.
4. Set the Field: Remaining and
5. Set the Table: Current_Delivery.
6. Set Update To: [Todays_Deliveries].[Remaining].

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

BEFORE:

**Todays_Deliveries**

```
ID   Date      Time  Ref  Studio Description Total Remaining
3187 23-Oct-12 10:00 3663 ROCK   PINK        1900  1900
```

**Current_Delivery**

```
ID   Date      Time  Ref  Studio Description Total Remaining
3187 23-Oct-12 10:00 3663 ROCK   PINK        1900  1000
```

AFTER:

**Todays_Deliveries**

```
ID   Date      Time  Ref  Studio Description Total Remaining
3187 23-Oct-12 10:00 3663 ROCK   PINK        1900  1000
```

UPDATE:

I've got the query working using the below function

```
UPDATE Todays_Deliveries SET Remaining = DLookup("Remaining","Current_Delivery","[MP-Ref] = Form![MP-Ref] And [Cat No] ='" & [Cat No] & "'")
WHERE "[MP-Ref] = Form![MP-Ref] And [Cat No] ='" & [Cat No] & "'";
```

Where *MP-Ref* is the delivery reference that list a number of items, and *Cat No* is the individual item reference.

The only problem is the other items in the _Daily_Deliveries_ table, the ones not in the _Current_Delivery_ table, have there remaining field set to 0 when I run it. Is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us 2 brief samples of rows from the 2 tables before UPDATE, and a third to show us what `Todays_Deliveries` should look like afterward.  In those samples, please exclude any fields which are not important for this question.  TIA.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to format it better

Comment: No worries, I did it.  Just select the rows, then click the format icon (`{}`) to format as code.

Comment: Incidentally, `Date`, `Time`, and `Description` are all reserved words.  If possible, rename those fields to avoid name conflicts.  If you can't rename them, enclose them in square brackets wherever they are present in your queries and unqualified by the table name or alias.

Comment: @HansUp Any idea why the records not specified in the WHERE clause are returning NULL?

Comment: It's too difficult for me to understand what's going on without adequate sample data to reference.  I have to bail on this one.